# Why do GC events occur at the same place in the app every time?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, responsive-design, garbage-collection

I am working on an AngularJS single page web application on an Android webview. For debugging I am using Chrome Remote Debugging tools. There is a problem I am having with the responsiveness of the app at a particular place.

Using a `$state.go()` call, I have a routing step into a particular view, that always seems to reliably and without fail, trigger GC events.

[image]

As you can see above, the GC events are affecting responsiveness for a couple of seconds whenever this view is navigated to. There is no forced GC call in the view's controller.

Comment: I would expect a state change to trigger GC since an entire state is thrown away, with its controllers, directives etc. If it occurs when navigating *into* a specific state, regardless of the initial state, then I would check again the initialization code for that state - maybe there is excessive object creation and destruction? It's hard to tell without seeing the application.

Comment: There _is_ actually a lot of initializing in that new state being routed to? You think that is what is causing the debug issue?

Comment: Could be, still hard to tell without seeing the code. You can experiment by commenting out code (or doing dummy-cheap initializations instead of the real-expensive ones).